# How to have different lightbox for different object

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys might be a very simple question, but i am playing around with a lightbox found [here](http://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/qsCkF). I got it on my site and its working, however i want to use it on a different page, but i cant, so i am guesing i might need to change the ID about or something? i am not to sure,

HTML:

```
<a id="show-panel" href="#">Show Panel</a>

<div id="lightbox-panel">
    <h2>Lightbox Panel</h2>
    <p>You can add any valid content here.</p>
    <p align="center"><a id="close-panel" href="#">Close this window</a></p>
</div>
<!-- /lightbox-panel -->
<div id="lightbox"></div>
<!-- /lightbox -->
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin:150px 0 0 0;
  text-align:center;
  background: #f1e7b0;
}
h2{
  font-size: 32px;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Lightbox background */
#lightbox {
  display:none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  z-index:1000;
}
/* Lightbox panel with some content */
#lightbox-panel {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-200px;
  width:400px;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
  border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
  z-index:1001;
}
```

So just to just fully be clear, i got it working for a one, but want to use the effect on anther object, i aien't to sure those how to change it so i can have diffrent content in the other one.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you "can't" use it on another page? Is it not displaying correctly? Because that's all going to depend on how it

Comment: @MikeC its fine, its just i want to use it in 2 places, the answer below is what i wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could even do it without JavaScript, as seen is this example below. All you need is to address the `:target` attribute with a corresponding `id` and `href`.

```css
.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.lightbox:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.lightbox > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

.close {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#lightbox-1">Box 1</a>

<div id="lightbox-1" class="lightbox">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">Close</a>
    <p>
      Box 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, et deleniti temporibus minus nisi voluptas molestias magni dolore qui, maxime blanditiis dolorem error nostrum, soluta exercitationem hic! Molestiae voluptas necessitatibus quo dignissimos
      quis nobis magni eaque veniam rerum nisi laboriosam rem natus sint amet voluptatem voluptatum explicabo voluptatibus animi, et.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#lightbox-2">Box 2</a>

<div id="lightbox-2" class="lightbox">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">Close</a>
    <p>
      Box 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad saepe non eos officia sequi, nemo quo ex facilis odio fuga ea eaque dolore perspiciatis obcaecati numquam reprehenderit consequuntur, repudiandae alias.
    </p>
  </div>
```